# Install specific version of .NET Core runtime on Linux

Tags: .net, linux, ubuntu, .net-core

How to install the most recent version of .NET Core runtime is well explained, basically

> sudo apt-get install dotnet-runtime-3.1

**What if we want to install specific version?**

Microsoft provides `dotnet-install.sh`. It is possible to do `dotnet-install.sh -Version 3.1.0 -Runtime aspnetcore`. However this script writes the binaries under $HOME/.dotnet. Also the runtime is not listed by `dotnet --info`.

How to install specific version of .NET Core runtime recognized by dotnet --info?

Comment: Which version do you want to install?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use

```
apt policy dotnet-sdk-3.1
```

to see a list of available versions. Then,

```
sudo apt-get install -y --allow-downgrades dotnet-sdk-3.1=3.1.301-1
```

Comment: This seems to work fine, thanks. Why did you add the --no-install-recommends flag? It doesn't seem to make a difference here... it always installs / updates the same number of packages, no matter if I add or remove this flag.

Comment: @stmax in this case it doesn't make a difference, I just copied it from one of my projects.

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu#how-to-install-other-versions);

> The packages added to the package manager feeds are named in a
> hackable format: `{product}-{type}-{version}`.
>
> Examples;
>
> - Install the ASP.NET Core 3.1 runtime: `aspnetcore-runtime-3.1`
> - Install the .NET Core 2.1 runtime: `dotnet-runtime-2.1`
> - Install the .NET Core 3.1 SDK: `dotnet-sdk-3.1`

Have a look at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu#supported-distributions) for supported packages for your Ubuntu version.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned this in my question - dotnet-runtime-3.1 will install the most recent version, currently this would be 3.1.3. What they don't mention is how to get older version, for example 3.1.2 - sudo apt install dotnet-runtime-3.1.2 will not work (Unable to locate package dotnet-runtime-3.1.2)